# drupal and ndb cluster engines

Tags: database

we have an application which was built with drupal connecting to a mysql db. upon go-live we found that the production db is a clustered one and requires us to change our db tables to NDB cluster engines.

Is drupal capable of working with clustered db's and how do we do this?

Answer (score 1):

## OBSERVATIONS

- Default Drupal installations use MyISAM storage engine
- Most plugins assume MyISAM storage engine for tables
- Many have switched to InnoDB

  - [What tables should or could be migrated to InnoDB, and which should remain MyISAM?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16778/what-tables-should-or-could-be-migrated-to-innodb-and-which-should-remain-myisa/16971#16971)
  - [How do I convert a database from MyISAM to InnoDB?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4753/how-do-i-convert-a-database-from-myisam-to-innodb/4794#4794)
  - FULLTEXT indexes not supported in InnoDB in MySQL 5.5
  - FULLTEXT indexes are supported in InnoDB in MySQL 5.6 (when it goes GA)

If is straightforwards to convert MyISAM to InnoDB, such as with the following:

```
ALTER TABLE node ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Not so with [**NDB**](http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/mysql-cluster-datasheet.pdf). For the table `node`, let's take the following approach:

```
mysqldump -u... -p... dbname --no-create-info node > node_data.sql
```

Then, load the table into the NDB Cluster

```
mysql -u... -p... -Ddbname -A < node_data.sql
```

and you let all the management nodes and SQL nodes determine where to store/shard the data.

If and only if you have the patience to

- upgrade Drupal
- avoid using FULLTEXT indexes (currently not supported by NDB)
- apply plugins

  - drop FULLTEXT indexes
  - convert any MyISAM tables to NDB
- migrate/reload data

then it is worth a shot.

Please post NDB Cluster questions in the [DBA StackExchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

DISCLAIMER : Not Drupal Expert, Not CMCDBA (not Cluster Certified), just CMDBA