# improve drupal 7 multisite performance

Tags: 7, performance, multi-sites

I think this has to be performed when the project is starting and not when the project is running, but, I don't decide that. I'm only the developer. I read a lot about performance in Drupal 7, and I saw modules like (Boost, Devel...) but I'm not very experienced with this.

Devel isn't working for my project (when I enter here admin/config/development/devel the page only stay await for a couple of seconds and return a problem with the server [The connection was reset] and nothing happen). AS of yet, I have not tried Boost.

I want to make performance improvements not only for Drupal way but also for Apache+MySQL. I read something and some guys talked about jMeter to make some stress test and other thing. buy, I want to know what you think, what you use and your experience dealing with performance.

(One answer will be: CACHE, but I'm looking something more than a cache).

So much thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

## Drupal

When it comes to multiple sites, you should consider what would be effects of managing multiple sites. Having a separate MySQL database for each Drupal site would means that your could do the following without disturbing others

- take one Drupal Site offline
- load new content into one site
- alter contents of one site

Consequences

- Upgrading Drupal content for one site may possibly affect others that are still running previous versions
- Doing an Upgrade requires a full shutdown of all sites
- Features for improving performance of one site (such as Boost Cache) may hurt performance for other sites

## MySQL

When it comes to MySQL, you will have to consider one of two things

- Using MyISAM Storage Engine
- Using InnoDB Storage Engine

MyISAM and InnoDB have strengths and weaknesses.

- MyISAM only caches Index Pages
- InnoDB caches data and index pages
- InnoDB can also be configured to have InnoDB bypass OS caching
- InnoDB can be configured to access multiple cores/CPUs
- There are some instances where MyISAM can be as fast or faster than InnoDB
- As of MySQL 5.5, only MyISAM supports FULLTEXT indexing. MySQL 5.6 will introduce FULLTEXT indexing to InnoDB

## Please see my past posts about other Pros and Cons:

- `May 03, 2012` : [Which is faster, InnoDB or MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/17434/877)
- `Sep 20, 2011` : [Best Of MyISAM and InnoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/6008/877)
- `Jun 07, 2011` : [How do I convert a database from MyISAM to InnoDB?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4753/how-do-i-convert-a-database-from-myisam-to-innodb/4794#4794)
- `Apr 15, 2011` : https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1715/what-would-be-the-optimal-mysql-configuration-for-a-drupal-7-site/2367#2367
- `Apr 14, 2011` : [What are the main differences between InnoDB and MyISAM?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/2194/877)