# How do I revert all of my DB tables from MyISAM back to InnoDB?

Tags: 7, database, backups

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I convert a database from MyISAM to InnoDB?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4753/how-do-i-convert-a-database-from-myisam-to-innodb)

Due to a bug in the Backup and Migrate module http://drupal.org/node/1128620 , all of my DB tables were reverted to MyISAM. How to return them all back to to InnoDB. (Perhaps using phpmyadmin?)

I used to use http://drupal.org/project/dbtuner/ in D6 for this. However there isn't a D7 version.

Also, are there any side effects or possible gotchas for switching this in this way?

Update:

```
<?php
    // connect your database here first 
    // 
    $sql = "SHOW tables";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql);

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
    {
        $tbl = $row[0];
        $sql = "ALTER TABLE $tbl  ENGINE=INNODB";
         mysql_query($sql);
    }
?>
```

What do I need to add to the section "connect your database here first" to connect to my Drupal DB?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856435/how-to-convert-all-tables-from-myisam-into-innodb

Comment: Any simple instructions for doing this in phpmyadmin?

Comment: THe following does not workSELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' engine=InnoDB;') 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE engine = 'MyISAM';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to take a backup with [Backup and Migrate](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate), open it in an editor and search/replace "MyISAM" to "InnoDB".  Then restore it.

Personally, I would restore to a new catalog, and then switch the database in settings.php.  This way, you can test before making the new version live.

Otherwise, this is a dup of [How do I convert a database from MyISAM to InnoDB?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/4753/how-do-i-convert-a-database-from-myisam-to-innodb)