# Drupal performance issue - too much time to establish a connection!

Tags: 6, performance

My drupal site was working fine. Then i disabled access to public with some session thing, After a week or something , it is taking more than 12 second to establish a connection, then the loading is real quick.

```
79 requests  ❘  35.47KB transferred  ❘  14.87s (onload: 14.87s, DOMContentLoaded: 13.06s)
home 
12.24s

css_6b268b79fc331b4fe1492e8a55b94a94.css
/sites/default/files/css
206ms

cometchatcss.php
394ms

........
```

another thing is its better for garland theme, so possibly theme problem , what what may cause this much waiting? not db_query as i checked even with **blank page.tpl** its taking 8+ sec! 
Please help!

Comment: `Warning: 'some session thing' is undefined. Please define it so we can help :)`. Also see http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36147/performance-problem-delay-on-first-request, it's probably related

Comment: actually it has nothing to do with slow issue, removed that session thing, but still it taking too much time!

Comment: Ah ok, far more likely to be one of the issues discussed on that other post then. First step...disable the auto-cron run and see if the problem magically goes away

Comment: It's not a 'problem' as such...The core cron run flushes the caches which makes the next page load take a long time. If you don't have cron on that cache flush doesn't happen, so you didn't get the delay

Comment: Sorry it didnt work.disabled poormans crone .. but still its 14+ sec to load a page!!

Comment: You'll need to profile the site then to find the bottleneck (the problem could be absolutely anything)

Comment: another thing is its better for garland theme, so possibly theme problem , what what may cause this much waiting? not db_query as i checked even with blank page.tpl its taking 8+ sec!

Comment: It's impossible to say without seeing all of the code from your theme, you need to profile the site with something like xhprof to see which functions are taking the longest time to run

Comment: Finally found problem - panel templates in my theme!! added as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found problem - panel templates in my theme

**for those who experience same , can follow these steps**

- my site is optimized with APC and mod_deflate, so in pagespeed for chrome test, its 93/100
- real problem was waiting time . chrome network analysis shows first GET took approx 18+ sec , then loading of other elements is real quick
- after several test, i found my theme is causing delay. so i put a blank page.tpl in my theme. And you know it took 12+ sec to load that blank page! so it was not any db query problem!
- so problem must be with .info, disabled css, then js, still no improvement
- finally removed panel template declaration from .info , and now site took .3 sec to load!
- next i tried with only one panel template in my theme, site took 1-2 sec

I have 10 panel templates in my theme.so panel templates affects site performance!

Comment: Better to add Panels templates using ctools layout plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing such issues. I had spent many hours in profiling and finding which module is causing problem. Unless you find the bottleneck you cannot fix it. I had explained it in a post. http://www.mindyourcode.com/php/drupal-profiling-performance-analysis-for-optimization-finding-the-performance-bottlenecks-in-your-application-at-core-level/