# Low first time to byte for my Drupal 7

Tags: performance

For the last months (without any significant change except modules and drupal core upgrades) I've been noticing that the First time to byte decreased from a not bad value (less than 300ms) to more than 2 - 3 seconds and I don't know why.

http://www.webpagetest.org/result/140518_61_6VV/1/details/

So I just moved from a shared hosting to a VPS but the First Time to Byte didn't change at all and I'm quite frustrated, could someone help me out please?

I'm using Boost, advagg, cache expiration and views content cache. Also I'm using Cloudflare as CDN but it didn't improve the performance either :(

I tried to analyze what's going on with the google developer tools (see attached image) but I cannot get enough information to figure out why so long waiting time.[image: google developer tools screenshot]

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This could be anything... Are you drawing data from external resouces? (I ran into this when fetching photo's from picasa, which took quite long). Drupal renders the page when all data is collected, so you'll have a 'slow' module somewhere.

Comment: How could I figure out if some module is fetching data from external resources?

Comment: Likely dup: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/36147/performance-problem-delay-on-first-request